# Windows Store App Transparent Background

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I am trying to make the background of my UWP app semi-transparent; I want to be able to partly see the desktop through it. I have tried setting the `Page`'s Background property to "Transparent", and setting the children's backgrounds to "Transparent". But it still shows a white background. Is this not possible, due to the mess it could create on phones, etc.? Or is there another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent UWP windows 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765969/transparent-uwp-windows-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `App.xaml.cs`, you can override a method called `OnWindowCreated(...)`. This will be called as soon as you have a new "chrome" to play with... and unfortunately, there's nothing there to allow you to change the opacity of the container.

You can also access this anytime after your app starts using `Window.Current`, which will give you the currently active window. Again... nothing there to allow opacity changes.

Maybe Microsoft will add this option in the future. So leave this question open for future answers :)

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Accepting, and will change if someone can ever give an answer that does it.

Answer (score -2):

Can you set the background to a transparent image?

Comment: Ummm... Sorry, what is this supposed to be attached to? The `Page`?

Comment: Whatever background is supposed to be transparent :)

Comment: Is this for UWP? `AddSolidFill` isn't an available method for my Background, and `SolidFill` isn't a resolvable class.

Comment: Hmm. I Guess I used that for The Google API in my Universal app :( Do you have any function where you can enter a hex code for color? I would enter all zeroes.

Comment: I can create one. I'll try that.