# Transparent UWP windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to figure out how to have a transparent background on the app, that lets the user see behind it. I've tried to change `background` and `opacity` parameters in `xaml` file, but nothing changed.

I have set a transparent image in background also

```
<Page.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/fond.png"/>
</Page.Background>
```

But it doesn't work

Does anyone know how to perform this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr 
**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic**

You will be able to do it after the update of Windows 10 that is coming.

Here:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/8232264-enable-blur-and-transparency-xaml-effects-to-allow?tracking_code=8e9425d1ccc153460b32b85ed3253c90

And the github:
https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%20Insider/BlurPlayground

[image]

Maybe it's not the straight "see through", but I think it's what you would like to have.

EDIT:
I think it is available in the SDK Preview, but I'm not sure because I didn't try it.

Info about Anniversary SDK Preview
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-developer-preview

SDK is here
https://insider.windows.com/

UPDATE:

I've just noticed prelease of CreateHostBackdropBrush() function in Compositor class. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor

UPDATE:

In Fall Creators Update it's even available as XAML code that's very fast and easy to write.

Link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic

Comment: Well, it start to looks like what I try to achieve. But is it already available for insider SDK or smth?

Comment: These Github examples require you to have the latest SDK (14332), so yes, it should be available there.

Comment: The screenshot here is a little bit misleading (it's just a concept design), the left pane is see-through to the desktop which is currently not possible.

Comment: I've just noticed prelease of CreateHostBackdropBrush() function in Compositor class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositor#Windows_UI_Composition_Compositor_CreateHostBackdropBrush

Answer (score 1):

I think the root cause that it is not possible to make your app background full transparent. I believe when you implement some image as background it will be possible to do.

Comment: Not sure if I got what you said, but I updated the post with what I think you were thinking about

Comment: Sorry, for misunderstanding. This is not possible now. You can vote for this feature at userVoice https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705/suggestions/14222889