# transparent app in windows 10 uwp

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to make a transparent app in windows 10 uwp. I searched stackoverflow and I found [Windows 10 UWP Transparent app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765969/transparent-uwp-windows-10) where they say the feature is available starting from release 14332. I have release 14393 but I can't figure out how to do it. I cannot access the git they suggest in the post: it gives me error 404

Comment: [BlurPlayground](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/BlurPlayground). Still, though, asking for off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow (see [help/on-topic]).

Comment: By "transparent app" do you mean the ability to see through the main app window to the desktop underneath? Because that's not currently possible.

Comment: Please check the sample link as @IInspectable provided. If still have issues about using, Update your issue.

Comment: Really not sure on this one, but this Library might be able to do it if you play the opacities on the Custom Acrylics. https://www.nuget.org/packages/UICompositionAnimations/