# UWP transparent window

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, transparency

I realize something like this has been asked before, but I would like to create an app with UI elements atop a transparent window (basically, an app without a window frame and with transparent background).

I've read the following posts:

- [transparent app in windows 10 uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045367/transparent-app-in-windows-10-uwp)
- [Transparent UWP windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765969/transparent-uwp-windows-10)

I checked the [BlurPlayground](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/BlurPlayground).

It seems that this isn't possible. However, the Sticky Notes application in Windows 10 is definitely managing to do this. Either this is some special API only available to Microsoft, or it can be done.

Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done in UWP today. The custom frame you see in Sticky Notes is a one-off implementation that does not have a public API.

Curious what is your scenario you want to accomplish here? (feel free to ping me offline - swick [at] Microsoft.com)

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform